# Fetch all towns/villages names using geonames api

Tags: java, geocoding, geonames

I am very new to GeoNames API and I need a hierarchical results say If I select Continent it will show all the countries and If I select a country I need to fetch all the states and so on.

Continent --> Country --> State --> Districts/Cities --> Towns --> Villages.

I need to build the above hierarchy. With the using of GeoNames API I was able to fetch till Districts/Cities but I was unable to fetch the Towns and Villages for particular District/City.

Is the GeoNames API doesn't have that database or is there any way to follow for getting Towns and Villages...???

Or else is there any separate API to achieve my task. I am fetching the records for a Country "INDIA".

Can any one help me on this. I stuck over here.

Thanq in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose they have the answer for this in the [GeoNames discussion baord](http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/518.page) already, thus do try the 'p' option with the fclass.